# Rails: Split and wrap each character in a string?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have something like:

```
<%= @votes %>
```

With just outputs a string like:

```
123
```

Is there a simple way to wrap each character with some html with a helper?

```
<span class="outerclass">
  <span class="innerclass">
  1
  </span>
</span>

<span class="outerclass">
  <span class="innerclass">
  2
  </span>
</span>

<span class="outerclass">
  <span class="innerclass">
  3
  </span>
</span>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a helper similar to this:

```
def wrap_each_char(string, &block)
  string.each_char.map(&block).join
end
```

Then use it like this (erb):

```
<%- @votes = "123" -%>
<%- wrap_each_char(@votes) do |c| -%>
  <span class="outer"><span class="inner"><%= c %></span></span>
<%- end -%>
```

**Update:** The above example represents one way to pass block level content to a helper, but it's worth noting that this particular example can be simplified by just using the `each_char` method on the string and avoiding the helper altogether:

```
<%- @votes.each_char do |c| -%>
  <span class="outer"><span class="inner"><%= c %></span></span>
<%- end -%>
```

Comment: If you're going to put all that in the view, why not just each?  (Which is in fact, exactly what I would actually do, but he asked for a helper)

Comment: Agreed, just using `each_char` in the view is more straight forward for the example given in the question, but I suspect he was looking more for an approach to a more general problem.  I read into the question such that he was looking for how to pass content from a block into a helper.

Comment: hmm.... this worked but it ended out being a little messier as I started adding more, so using the `content_tag` as a block turned out to be a little nicer. Plus Eric is new, so he needs some points.

Answer (score 2):

view:

```
<% @votes.split('').each do |v| %>
  <%= print_vote(v) %>
<% end %>
```

helper:

```
def print_vote(vote)
  content_tag(:span, :class => 'outerclass') do
    content_tag(:span, vote, :class => 'innerclass')
  end
end
```

I'd work toward array'ing the votes before they hit the view, but you're going to have to iterate somewhere and the split doesn't really add much to the implementation anyway. I guess if you really wanted to stuff everything in the helper you could do something like

view:

```
<%= print_votes(@votes) %>
```

helper:

```
def print_votes(votes)
  votes.split('').each do |vote|
    content_tag(:span, :class => 'outerclass') do
      content_tag(:span, vote, :class => 'innerclass')
    end
  end
end
```

Pretty much the same, it just depends on where you want to put your lines.

Comment: i like this one the most, oddly enough it doesn't actually output the tags, give it a try, perhaps I'm dong it wrong.

Comment: I just edited to add a missing `%>` in the view chunk, so make sure you have that. I've just checked TFM and I think my content_tag nesting is unsupported, so I've changed it to use a block instead.

Comment: oops, I had also forgotten the `.split` in the second helper method.

Comment: I think that the split fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

```
# View
<%= char_classes(@votes) %>

# Helper
def char_classes(string)
  string.split.map { |char| '<span class="outerclass"><span class="innerclass">' + char + '</span></span>'}.join
end
```

You'll probably want to choose more expressive method/var names...